# How to run only unmarked tests in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have several markers in my python test code:

```
@pytest.mark.slowtest
@pytest.mark.webtest
@pytest.mark.stagingtest
```

I am able to selectively run tests with a marker using for example `pytest -m slowtest`

How can I run unmarked tests without resorting to `pytest -m "not (slowtest or webtest or stagingtest)"`?

As you can imagine, we might use other markers in the future...

Comment: I think that running `pytest`, without the `-m` flag, will run unmarked tests.

Comment: unfortunately `pytest` without `-m` runs all tests, including those with markers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Couldn't find anything yet. I guess one solution would be to invent your own default marker `unmarkedtest` and run these "unmarked" tests explicitly as well.

Answer (score 8):

Another option I found useful is to use `pytest.ini` to add default options. We explicitly write which markers to skip. It entails mainlining the list of skipped markers in `pytest.ini`. In other words, not 100% what the OP asked for but this is the best SO question I found when looking for default markers. Hopefully, this can help others.

From the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-addopts):

```
addopts

    Add the specified OPTS to the set of command line arguments as if they had been specified by the user. Example: if you have this ini file content:

    # content of pytest.ini
    [pytest]
    addopts = --maxfail=2 -rf  # exit after 2 failures, report fail info

    issuing pytest test_hello.py actually means:

    pytest --maxfail=2 -rf test_hello.py

    Default is to add no options.
```

What I added to my pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = -m "not slow"
markers =
    slow: marks tests as slow (deselect with '-m "not slow"')
```

Using it

```sh
﮸$ grep 'mark.slow' tests/*.py | wc -l
3

$ pytest -s
======================================================= test session starts ========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /tests, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 66 items / 3 deselected / 63 selected                                                                                    

../tests/test_app.py ...............................................................

================================================= 63 passed, 3 deselected in 8.70s =================================================
```

Comment: Note that you can use: 'and', 'or'  within parentheses if you want to enable/disable more types of tests. For example: addopts = -m "not slow and not sth_else".

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your conftest will solve this for you by adding a specific mark to all unmarked test so you can then run something like `pytest -m unmarked`

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    for item in items:
        if not any(item.iter_markers()):
            item.add_marker("unmarked")
```

This has the advantage over the how pytest-unmarked does it in that you can still specify other markers e.g. `pytest -m 'webtest or unmarked'`. Also pytest-unmarked doesn't look maintained and emits warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code snippet in top level conftest.py.

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    envmarker = item.get_marker()
    if envmarker:
        pytest.skip("Skipping as the test has a marker")
```

Remember that parametrize is also a marker. If you are using parametrization, you can check for that in envmarker and skip conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

The [pytest-unmarked plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-unmarked/) is intended to accomplish this.

PyPi's link to the project's home is broken. This is the proper link https://github.com/alyssabarela/pytest-unmarked

More info on using plugins at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html

Comment: This seems utterly broken with current pytest -- even when not passing the `--unmarked` flag, it causes an exception.